# Changing text in a captured group

Tags: python, regex, django

With the code I'm using `(r' ', ' '),` changes to `a a a a(r' a', a' a'),` when it should change to `(r' a', ' '),`. What's a more natural way to do this? How do I do this with `re.sub`?

Current code, see [here](http://pastebin.com/cQvJ81BF)

```
for key, value in newgroupdict.items():
    try:
        newstr = newstr.replace(re.search(e, line).group(key), value)
    except:
        pass
```

Examples:

```
Expression: \s*(?:url)?\(r?["|'](?P<pattern>[^'"]+)["|'],\s*["|']?direct_to_template["|']?,\s*{["|']template["|']:\s*["|'](?P<template>[^'"]+)["|']}\),
String:     (r'^$', direct_to_template, {'template': 'home.html'}),
Dictionary: {u'pattern': u'^$abc', u'type': u'direct to template', u'template': u'home.html'}
Output:     (r'^$abc', direct_to_template, {'template': 'home.html'}),

Expression: \s*(?:url)?\(r?["|'](?P<pattern>[^'"]+)["|'],\s*["|']?(?P<view>[^'"]+)["|']?\),
String:     (r'^urls/', 'urls.views.urls'),
Dictionary: {u'pattern': u'^new_urls_pattern/', u'type': u'view', u'view': u'urls.views.urls'}
Output:     (r'^new_urls_patterns/', 'urls.views.urls'),

================= Incorrect Output ========================

Expression: \s*(?:url)?\(r?["|'](?P<pattern>[^'"]+)["|'],\s*["|']?(?P<view>[^'"]+)["|']?\),
String:     (r'^urls/', 'urls'),
Dictionary: {u'pattern': u'^new_urls_pattern/', u'type': u'view', u'view': u'urlsxyz'}
Incorrect Output:     (r'^urlsxyz/', 'urlsxyz'),
Correct Output:     (r'^urls/', 'urlsxyz'),
```

[image: screenshot of djangogui]

Comment: I find your question quite underspecified. You only give one replacement example, but your code loops through a whole list of replacements. Please provide us with more input/output pairs or a more thorough description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, but who is going to read that? You want us to help you with your problem, so please put some effort into boiling down the problem to what is relevant, while still providing enough examples for us to actually grasp what you want to accomplish.

Comment: [Are You A Movie Director Or Something?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles) Also, I'm still confused by the desired effect. Can you describe the substitution you want in words, or give another example?

Comment: Added examples and screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this with a regexp, here's one:

```
In [23]: re.sub(r"'([^']+)'", r"'\1a'", "(r' ', ' '),", 1)
Out[23]: "(r' a', ' '),"
```

I'm not a good teacher and regexps are tricky to understand, still I'll try to break this down to you:

- Using [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), arguments used:

  - first argument is regexp,
  - second is *replacement* regexp,
  - third is subject, the string you want to work,
  - and finnaly is the number of times to apply the replacement,
- Using the first regexp:

  1. `'` will match a `'` in your string subject,
  2. `(` opens group `\1`, anything found between this and `)` will be in group `\1`,
  3. `[^']` matches any character **except `'`**,
  4. `+` means that the previous character class (`[^']`) can be repeated,
  5. `'` will match the `'`
- The replacement regexp says:

  - put `'` to compensate for the replaced `'` in 1.,
  - put whatever was matched in group `\1`, everything from 2. to 4., all non `'` characters,
  - put `'` to compensate for the last `'` that is in the pattern regexp,

Feel free to experiment with it, remove the count argument and stuff like that. But you will **have** to learn regexp at some point, so you should see that as a great opportunity to read [the holy manual](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Knowing to regexp will make you a much better programmer and give you power over text data.